# Find replace in directory IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

How to find and replace text in all files under specific folder?

Is there any shortcut. It should be.

And
It is not `CTRL+R.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CTRL+SHIFT+R and will get more manageable replace.